# Windows .BAT - Move File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the below structure:

```
/fooFolder
    /js
        /classes
        /interfaces
    /ts
        /classes
            file.js
            file.ts
        /interfaces
            file.js
            file.ts
    move.bat
```

I need move the file **~/ts/classes/file.js** to **js/classes** and the file **~/ts/interfaces/file.js** to **js/interfaces** using the file **move.bat**.

I try using the code below:

```
forfiles /s /m *.js /c "cmd /c move /Y @path %~dp0..\@relpath"
```

Unfortunately, I receive a syntax error message.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
forfiles /s /m *.js /c "cmd /c move /Y @path ..\..\js\@relpath"
```

Works! But... Is the better?